# passing member functions as parameters / c++

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I would like to implement, in c++, a class **b** where it would be possible to do some kind of iteration through a member set encapsulating the type of that iterator. Like:

```
b_object.for_each_x_do(function_f);
```

so **function_f** would get everyone of the **x** members and do anything. Let's say:

```
void function_f(x_member_type x){ cout << x << endl; }
```

Ok. So I'm trying to achieve that through a code like:

```
class b{
    int *x;
public:
    void foreach_x_do(void (*f)(int)){
            while(*x++)  // or any kind of iteration through x
                    f(*x);
    }
};

class a{
    b b_inst;
public:
    void f(int x) {  }     
    a(){
            b_inst.foreach_x_do(f); // by mistake it was b_inst.foreach_x_do(f)(), however this wasn't the point at all. 
    }
    ~a(){}
};

int main(){}
```

However, I'm getting this error, compile-time:

> fp.cpp: In constructor `‘a::a()’`:
>   fp.cpp:17: error: no matching function for call to `‘b::foreach_x_do(<unresolved overloaded  function type>)’`
>   fp.cpp:6: note: candidates are: `void b::foreach_x_do(void (*)(int))`

Anybody can help getting it to compile?

Comment: For one thing, the `f` you are passing to `foreach_x_do` is not a `void(*)(int)` it is a `void (a::*)(int)`.

Comment: Just a sidenote, you should probably name your classes with uppercase. So `class B` instead of `class b`. Just to conform to common ussage.

Comment: [This FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) will give you more information than you want to know about passing member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be:

```
b_inst.foreach_x_do(f);
```

You also need to make `f` static, not a non-static member method since the original signature for your `foreach_x_do` function is for a stand-alone function pointer, not a pointer-to-member-function.  So i.e.,

```
static void f(int x) {  }
```

Comment: i don't know if there any traps with this solution (since the method becomes static) but for my simple task it works good. Maybe the solutions using bind() are better, but I liked this one because it is more compiler-independent.

Comment: The main "trap" is that the static function cannot directly access a non-static member or method of the class ... so if you need to access a non-static data-member or method, you'll have to pass a reference or pointer to the class-object as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 2):

As @steveo225 noted, `f` in that context is of type `void (a::*)(int)` rather than `void (*)(int)`. There are two approaches to fixing this -- the first is to make `b::foreach_x_do` a member function template that takes any callable type:

```
class b {
    int* x;

public:
    b() : x() { }
    template<typename F>
    void foreach_x_do(F f) {
        while(*x++)
            f(*x);
    }
};

class a {
    b b_inst;

public:
    void f(int x) { }
    a() : b_inst() {
        b_inst.foreach_x_do(std::bind(&a::f, this, _1));
    }
};
```

---

The second is to keep `b::foreach_x_do` a non-template and have it take a `std::function<>` instead of a function pointer:

```
class b {
    int* x;

public:
    b() : x() { }
    void foreach_x_do(std::function<void(int)> const& f) {
        while(*x++)
            f(*x);
    }
};

class a {
    b b_inst;

public:
    void f(int x) { }
    a() : b_inst() {
        b_inst.foreach_x_do(std::bind(&a::f, this, _1));
    }
};
```

---

In either case, replace `std::bind` and `std::function` with their `boost::` counterparts if your compiler is too old to ship with `std::` or `std::tr1::` implementations. Also note that if you have a C++11 compiler, you can use a lambda instead of `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `for_each_x_do` is expecting a function pointer, while you're (trying) to give it a member function pointer. The two are not the same. The former can be called directly, while the latter requires an object instance to be called. I'd suggest you use `std::function` or `boost::function` instead. Something like:

```
void for_each_x_do(function<void (int)> f) {
  // your code here
}
```

And then use a binder to construct a function object:

```
a(){
  b_inst.foreach_x_do(bind(&a::f, this, _1));     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
 b_inst.foreach_x_do(f)();
```

Remove the second set of parenthesis; you don't need them.

```
 b_inst.foreach_x_do(f);
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`f()` is a **member** function -- so it's relevance is limited to it's corresponding object.  Some of these solutions so far won't work.

You have two choices, either make the function static, in which case it doesn't matter which object, or somehow also pass the object.

The second method is clearly explained in [this helpful FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) specifically about passing member functions.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
class b{
int *x;
public:
void foreach_x_do(void (*f)(int)){
        while(*x++)  // or any kind of iteration through x
                (*f)(*x);
}
```

};