# C++ functor templates

Tags: c++, templates, functor

Given the following class, which simply maps an internal functor `f` to a function to be run later:

```
class A {
private:
   int (A::*f)(int);
   int foo(int x) { return x; }
   int bar(int x) { return x*2; }
public:
   explicit A(bool foo=true) { f = foo ? &A::foo : &A::bar; }
   int run(int x) { return (this->*f)(x); }
};
```

Now say I have another class, `B`:

```
class B {
public:
   int foo(int) { return x*x; }
};
```

And function `foo`:

```
int foo(int x) { return 0; }
```

I know it is not possible to have `A` assign and run `B::foo` or `foo` as their prototypes differ: `int (A::*)(int)` vs `int (B::*)(int)` vs `int (*)(int)`.

What I am asking, is their any way to templatize `A::f` such that it could take any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but you may want to look into:

- [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/function/index.html) - can wrap any kind of callable
- [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html) - can be used to bind a member function to an instance

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you use a `std::`/`boost::`/`std::tr1` `::function<int(int)>` for this kind of job. It can take any function object (including pointer) with the correct signature. You can create function objects that call member functions using `bind`, available in the same package.

Comment: I will admit unfamiliarity with boost, heard of it, never used it. What would the prototype of `f` be in the case of my example such that `f` could be assigned any of the functions (`A::foo`, `B::foo`, and `foo`)? Just `function<int(int)> f;` And how would it be assigned? `f = &::foo;`, `B b; f = &b.foo`.

Comment: @steveo225: Read the documentation.

Comment: I see that now that Space_C0wb0y posted it

Comment: @steveo225 : I gave examples of this in [the other thread you just posted in](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6063112/636019).

Comment: @ildjarn: That's hilarious. That question is what sparked me thinking of this. I often use functors, but never thought of using like that until I read that question. Then I got excited at all the possibilities.